# c++ replace a string with another string without built in functions

Tags: c++, string

```
void substitute(string stringuser, string subs1, string subs2)
{
    string vchar;
    for (int i = 0; i < stringuser.length(); i++)
    {
        vchar = stringuser[i];
        if (vchar == subs1)
        {
            newstring+=subs2;
        }
        else
        {
            vchar = stringuser[i];
            newstring+=vchar;
        }
    }
}
```

this is the code I wrote to replace a character in a string with another character. However, it should work for 2 or more characters withal, not only 1. The problem is I have no idea how to do it and I'd appreciate any help I can get with the task :)

Comment: Break it down. First write a function that finds instances of the substring in the big string. Until you can do that you can't replace the substring, so there's not much point to asking about replacement.

Comment: Side note: `stringuser` should almost certainly be passed by reference if you're going to change it

Comment: I do have a function to get a substring from a given index to a given index: 

`void substring(string &stringuser, int subsn1, int subsn2)
{
    string vchar;
    if (subsn2 > stringuser.length())
    {
        subsn2 = stringuser.length();
    }
    for (int i = subsn1 - 1; i < subsn2; i++)
    {
        vchar = stringuser[i];
        newstring+=vchar;
    }
    stringuser = newstring;
}`


do i have to use this code for the substitute function aswell?

Answer (score 0):

`std::string` has [`find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and [`replace()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace) methods that work with substrings, eg:

```cpp
string substitute(string stringuser, string subs1, string subs2)
{
    string::size_type pos, start = 0;
    while ((pos = stringuser.find(subs1, start)) != string::npos)
    {
        stringuser.replace(pos, subs1.size(), subs2);
        start = pos + subs2.size();
    }
    return stringuser;
}
```

If you are not allowed to use them, then replace them with your own implementations, eg:

```cpp
string::size_type indexOf(const string &stringuser, const string &subs, string::size_type start = 0)
{
    if (start < stringuser.size())
    {
        for(string::size_type i = start; i < stringuser.size(); ++i)
        {
            if (stringuser[i] == subs[0])
            {
                if ((stringuser.size() - i) < subs.size()) {
                    break;
                }
                bool match = true;
                for(string::size_type j = 1; j < subs.size(); ++j)
                {
                    if (stringuser[i+j] != subs[j])
                    {
                        match = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (match) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return string::npos;
}

string subString(const string &stringuser, string::size_type pos = 0, string::size_type count = string::npos)
{
    if (pos > stringuser.size()) {
         throw std::out_of_range("");
    }
    if ((count == string::npos) || ((stringuser.size() - pos) > count) {
        count = stringuser.size() - pos;
    }
    string newstring;
    newstring.reserve(count);
    for(string::size_type i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        newstring += stringuser[pos+i];
    }
    return newstring;
}

string substitute(const string &stringuser, const string &subs1, const string &subs2)
{
    string newstring;
    string::size_type pos, start = 0;
    while ((pos = indexOf(stringuser, subs1, start)) != string::npos)
    {
        if (pos > start) {
            newstring += subString(stringuser, start, pos - start);
        }
        newstring += subs2;
        start = pos + subs2.size();
    }
    if (start < stringuser.size()) {
        newstring += subString(stringuser, start);
    }
    return newstring;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare one character with a whole string, but you have to also check characters next to `stringuser[i]`. It can be done this way:

```
string substitute(string stringuser, string subs1, string subs2)
{
    string newstring;
    char vchar;
    for (int i = 0; i < stringuser.length(); i++)
    {
        vchar = stringuser[i];
        if (vchar == subs1[0])
        {
            int j;
            for (j = 1; j < subs1.length(); j++)    //We have to compare all symbols
            {
                if (i + j >= stringuser.length())
                    break;
                if (subs1[j] != stringuser[i + j])
                    break;
            }
            if (j == subs1.length())    //If cycle ended succesfully
            {
                newstring += subs2;
                i += subs1.length()-1;  //Skip remaining characters from subs1  
            }
            else
                newstring += vchar;
        }
        else
        {
            vchar = stringuser[i];
            newstring += vchar;
        }
    }
    return newstring;
}
```